# Gráfico de barras agrupadas com linha de média móvel no R

Tags: r

Olá, estou com uma dúvida para estruturar um gráfico no R.

Minha intenção é utilizar um gráfico de barras agrupadas, com uma linha de média móvel acima dele.

O gráfico que tenho é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de que a média móvel, para cada um dos pontos (P1 a P9) fosse relacionada a cada uma das três coletas citadas na legenda, de forma a ficar semelhante a seguinte figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são os dados que tenho:

```
        P1    P2    P3    P4    P5    P6    P7    P8    P9            
coleta_1 = 0.73, 0.90, 1.24, 1.18, 0.79, 0.84, 0.51, 0.90, 0.67

coleta_2 = 2.44, 2.50, 1.26, 1.80, 2.05, 2.78, 1.05, 1.57, 1.85

coleta_3 = 1.04, 2.08, 1.08, 1.04, 0.65, 0.73, 1.56, 0.53, 1.24
```

Basicamente cada índice das strings acima são um ponto da coleta. Ou seja, 0.73 , 2.44 e 1.04 são P1, enquanto 0.90 , 2.50 , 2.08 são P2 e assim sucessivamente.

Como eu poderia fazer?
Obrigado pela disponibilidade!

Comment: Por *"média móvel"* quer dizer média das três coletas em cada `P`?

Answer (score 2):

O gráfico base é simples, chama-se `barplot` e depois `legend` para a legenda do gráfico.

O passo importante é guardar a saída de `barplot`, para depois usar em `spline`.

```
cores <- c("#2e8b57", "#9acd32", "#4eee94")
lgnd <- paste("Coleta", 1:3)

bp <- barplot(dados, beside = TRUE, main = "Dados Clorofila", col = cores, ylim = c(0, 4))
legend("top", legend = lgnd, fill = cores, horiz = TRUE, box.col = NA)

mean_line <- spline(bp[2, ], colMeans(dados))
lines(mean_line$x, mean_line$y, col = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Dados

```
dados <-
structure(c(0.73, 2.44, 1.04, 0.9, 2.5, 2.08, 1.24, 1.26, 1.08, 
1.18, 1.8, 1.04, 0.79, 2.05, 0.65, 0.84, 2.78, 0.73, 0.51, 1.05, 
1.56, 0.9, 1.57, 0.53, 0.67, 1.85, 1.24), .Dim = c(3L, 9L),
 .Dimnames = list(c("coleta_1", "coleta_2", "coleta_3"), 
 c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9")))
```